# query string param is not url-encoded inside asp.net mvc action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, urlencode

I'm calling ResetPassword action from an Email (ASP.NET MVC 5).

```
http://localhost:34162/Account/ResetPassword?code=BwEA181bAECFMcn1vwPdrctS/wcyncKPxGT9Zx1tDuPwKGpe9H1W7LI3Zm9fM+3aA5Fok5GhLPBHqbtiGfpL8Cmdx7RNC6RJ7d6t9ZgFBwgwYk3zssU1Nh64PWHJAabVG9Wv9VWDNdj+Fz0UA712XA==
```

This is the address in my Browser.

However, in debug I receive this string in the ResetPassword Action:

```
    // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
    {
        return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
    }
```

The 'code' is:

```
BwEA181bAECFMcn1vwPdrctS/wcyncKPxGT9Zx1tDuPwKGpe9H1W7LI3Zm9fM 3aA5Fok5GhLPBHqbtiGfpL8Cmdx7RNC6RJ7d6t9ZgFBwgwYk3zssU1Nh64PWHJAabVG9Wv9VWDNdj Fz0UA712XA==
```

i.e., it is not url-encoded and of course password is not reset with invalid token message.

What can I do for getting the right string in the Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what was the problem. Looks like it shouldn't have worked in the first place. I wish I knew why Microsoft feel the need to use tokens with slashes and pluses.

Anyway, I just Base64 encoded and decoded the token as follows:

before sending the Email to the user:

...

```
            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

            code = CommonFuncs.Base64Encode(code);

            EmailsBL.PasswordResetEmail(model.Email, code); <-- emailing the link for password rest to the user
```

And then when receiving:

```
    // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // NOTE: if email is not CONFIRMED then reset password silently fails
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        model.Code = CommonFuncs.Base64Decode(model.Code);
```

i.e., decoding the token.

This following is just for completeness:

```
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        string base64string = null;
        if (plainText != null)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            base64string = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
        return base64string;
    }

    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        string decodedBase64String = null;
        if (base64EncodedData != null)
        {
            var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
            decodedBase64String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        }
        return decodedBase64String;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the string in the following way:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
{
    code = Server.HtmlEncode(code);
}
```

Fore more information on how to encode you can look at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx